# Set column names during OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

### Issue

I am currently trying to prefix my tables and their columns via an attribute that is set. I am using Entity Framework Core. I've gotten it right to prefix the table name but I cannot seem to figure it out for the columns. I have a feeling I will need to use reflection.

I have left my (probably poor) attempt at reflection in. Does someone have a way of setting the name of a column in an entity?

---

### Code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Debugger.Launch();
    //Loop though each entity to set table names correctly
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        //Get the custom attributes of the entity
        var attributes = entity.ClrType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        //Throw exception if there isn't any custom attribute applied to the class
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity), "Entity is missing table prefix.");

        //Get the table prefix
        var prefix = attributes[0];

        //Set the table name
        entity.Relational().TableName = prefix + entity.Relational().TableName;

        //Loop through all the columns and apply the prefix
        foreach (var prop in entity.GetProperties())
        {
            var propInfo = entity.ClrType.GetProperty(prop.Name);
            propInfo.SetValue(entity.ClrType, prefix + prop.Name, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's similar to what you did with the table name. Just use the [Relational()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmetadataextensions.relational?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalMetadataExtensions_Relational_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableProperty_) extension method of `IMutableProperty` and [ColumnName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.relationalpropertyannotations.columnname?view=efcore-2.1) property:

```
foreach (var prop in entity.GetProperties())
{
    prop.Relational().ColumnName = prefix + prop.Relational().ColumnName;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!